# Mapping multibyte characters to their unicode point representation

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

How do you map a single UTF-8 character to its unicode point in C?
[For example, `È` would be mapped to `00c8`].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your platform's `wchar_t` stores unicode (if it's a 32-bit type, it probably does) and you have an UTF-8 locale, you can call `mbrtowc` (from C90.1).

```
mbstate_t state = {0};
wchar_t wch;
char s[] = "\303\210";
size_t n;
memset(&state, 0, sizeof(state));
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8"); /*error checking omitted*/
n = mbrtowc(&wch, s, strlen(s), &state);
if (n <= (size_t)-2) printf("%lx\n", (unsigned long)wch);
```

For more flexibility, you can call the [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) interface.

```
char s[] = "\303\210";
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UCS-4");
if (cd != -1) {
    char *inp = s;
    size_t ins = strlen(s);
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t *outp = &c;
    size_t outs = 0;
    if (iconv(cd, &inp, &ins, &outp, &outs) + 1 >= 2) printf("%lx\n", c);
    iconv_close(cd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I probably want `iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UCS-2");`.

Comment: You're right -- "UCS-*" is mentioned in the `iconv` header document. I missed that (I tried lots of other combinations). Your answer is exactly what needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to look at :

- libiconv
- ConvertUTF.h
- MultiByteToWideChar (under windows)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'm a little confused - I thought `iconv` was for changing the encoding, not for mapping to representations as strings. Perhaps I'm missing something glaring.

Comment: @SK9: a string's encoding is the way its characters are represented, so I'm confused as to where you're confused.

Comment: I hadn't realised "UCS-2" was available.

Answer (score 0):

An reasonably fast implementation of an UTF-8 to UCS-2 converter. Surrogate and characters outside the BMP left as exercice.
The function returns the number of bytes consumed from the input `s` string. A negative value represents an error.
The resulting unicode character is put at the address `p` points to.

```
int utf8_to_wchar(wchar_t *p, const char *s)
{
const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *)s;
   p[0] = 0;
   if(!*us)
     return 0;
    else 
      if(us[0] < 0x80) {
        p[0] = us[0];
        return 1;
      }
      else 
        if(((us[0] & 0xE0) == 0xC0) && (us[1] & 0xC0) == 0x80) {
          p[0] = ((us[0] & 0x1F) << 6) | (us[1] & 0x3F);
#ifdef DETECT_OVERLONG
          if(p[0] < 0x80) return -2;
#endif    
          return 2;
        }
        else 
          if(((us[0] & 0xF0) == 0xE0) && (us[1] & 0xC0) == 0x80 && (us[2] & 0xC0) == 0x80) {
            p[0] = ((us[0] & 0x0F) << 12) | ((us[1] & 0x3F) << 6) | (us[2] & 0x3F);
#ifdef DETECT_OVERLONG
          if(p[0] < 0x800) return -2;
#endif    
            return 3;
          }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: I think you got the three-byte case wrong. You need to treat `s` as an `unsigned char*` all along, but even then, I get `0xe201c` for `“` (\U{201c}).

Comment: Wow, I have now understood the 0xe201c and why it didn't happen on our implementation. We have a 16bit wchar_t, so the `0xe2 << 12` oveflows the 16bit  word and the result is 0x2000 and not 0xe2000 word.

Comment: -1 for dangerous code that accepts invalid sequences. Don't roll your own unless you know what you're doing!

Comment: Which invalid sequences? It doesn't support 4 byte sequences and it doesn't check for the surrogate space, but that was said in the text above. Implementing its own (limited) version is sometimes necessary where compiler are outdated and the system doesn't provide libraries (embedded systems).